# android autocompletetextview should show only relevant options in drop down

Tags: android, filtering, autocompletetextview, android-optionsmenu

I am using a AutoCompleteTextView in my code and loading the list from database using SimpleCursorAdapter.

```
AutoCompleteTextView cocktailIngredientView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.item);
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mCursor,
                new String[] { "field" },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
cocktailIngredientView.setAdapter(adapter);
cocktailIngredientView.setThreshold(0);
```

It populates the list correctly but I have two issues:

1. I want this list to be sorted
2. Whatever I enter, it displays the complete list. I want it to filter based on matching patterns in the list. e.g. if the list contains values Page, Tools...then if I enter T in the box, the drop-down should show only Tools. The idea is to display options which contain the entered pattern anywhere in the string text.

How can this be done?

Comment: Further when i select any item in the drop down it shows android.database.sqlite...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tell the adapter what items to display. I tried implementing something similar to this by using a [`FilterQueryProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FilterQueryProvider.html) that queries the database for the items that I want to display in the dropdown.

```
FilterQueryProvider filter = new FilterQueryProvider() {

    @Override
    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
        // Make a DB query that filters based on the constraint

        return //whatever query results;
    }
};
myAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(filter);
```

As for the situation when you select an item on the list, you have to override the [`CursorToStringConverter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter.html) of the `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Something like:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter conv = new SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter() {

    @Override
    public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
        int numCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("whateverFieldYouNeed");
        String term = cursor.getString(numCol);
        return term;
    }
};
myAdapter.setCursorToStringConverter(conv);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really worked for me.But using the filterquery provider, one thing that i observed is that the last item in the filtered list doesnt appear fully. I see a scroll bar, and to view it fully I have to scroll down. It is by default visible only half.

Comment: Try playing around with the `setDropDownHeight()` [1] method to adjust how many items are visible in the dropdown menu.

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setDropDownHeight(int)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `CursorToStringConverter` you could also use

```
mAdapter.setStringConversionColumn(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("whateverFieldYouNeed"));
```